# Why is the "mango fly" called a "mango fly"?

Tags: terminology

> Cordylobia anthropophaga, **the mango fly**, tumbu fly, tumba fly, putzi
> fly, or skin maggot fly, is a species of blow-fly common in East and
> Central Africa. <sub>[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordylobia_anthropophaga)</sub>

Why is Cordylobia anthropophaga among other names called the mango fly? I can't seem to find anything online about why they gave it this name, and I figure they don't eat mangos.